# how to get another function in another controller (Codeigniter)

Tags: function, codeigniter, view, admin, crud

i made controller name crud.php this the code :

```
class Crud extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();      
        $this->load->model('m_data');
                $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function admin(){
        $data['produk'] = $this->m_data->tampil_data()->result();
        $this->load->view('v_admin',$data);
    }
}
```

i want take the `admin()` to place in admin.php code here :

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        if($this->session->userdata('status') != "login"){
            redirect(base_url("login"));
        }
    }

    function index(){
        $this->crud->admin();
    }
}
```

what's code for take another function in another controller.. that's possible or not?

Comment: you can use the redirect function - is there any reason why you don't want to do that ?

Comment: Normal codeigniter can not call another controllers function you need to use the latest HMVC third party plugin https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Answer (score 0):

You could try to `require` Crud controller within Admin controller :

```
public function index()
{
    require_once('crud.php');
    $crud = new crud();
    $crud->admin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood your question very well, but you could have the controller Admin extend the Crud controller, so he would have access to the admin ()

```
class Admin extends Crud{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        if($this->session->userdata('status') != "login"){
            redirect(base_url("login"));
        }
    }

    function index(){
        $this->admin();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading another controller inside a controller is a bad idea. It can lead to hard to find bugs. One solution is to make `Crud` a custom library that the controller loads.

File: **/application/libraries/Crud.php**

```
class Crud
{
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI = & get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->model('m_data');
        $this->CI->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function admin()
    {
        $data['produk'] = $this->CI->m_data->tampil_data()->result();
        $this->CI->load->view('v_admin', $data);
    }
}
```

Then the controller loads and uses the custom class.

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        if($this->session->userdata('status') != "login"){
            redirect(base_url("login"));
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('crud');
        $this->crud->admin();
    }
}
```

You could load `crud` in the constructor too. That would make sense if other methods in the controller use the library.

Answer (score 0):

May it can be useful for you, if you will customize your code in the view:

VIEW

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('crud/admin') ?>">your-link-to-another-controller</a>
```